# Rails app crashes when deploying to Azure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy a rails application as a WebApp on Azure. I tried following this [guide](https://medium.com/paris-rb/deploying-your-rails-postgresql-app-on-microsoft-azure-180f8a9fab47). The deploy goes ok. But when I try to access the page in the browser it crashes.

```
2020-09-10T20:08:46.739615274Z running bundle install  --local --path vendor/bundle
2020-09-10T20:08:47.601183687Z Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
2020-09-10T20:08:47.602571397Z installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
2020-09-10T20:08:47.602587497Z users on this machine.
2020-09-10T20:08:48.118327788Z Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.17.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
2020-09-10T20:08:48.360206948Z The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
2020-09-10T20:08:48.509477972Z Could not find rake-12.3.3 in any of the sources
2020-09-10T20:08:48.517855329Z defaulting to command: "bundle exec rails server -e production -p 8080"
2020-09-10T20:08:49.353444362Z bundler: command not found: rails
2020-09-10T20:08:49.354345768Z Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
2020-09-10T20:08:50.336Z ERROR - Container myapp_0_4ec4bebe for site myapp has exited, failing site start
2020-09-10T20:08:50.353Z ERROR - Container myapp_0_4ec4bebe didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2020-09-10T20:08:50.382Z INFO  - Stopping site myapp because it failed during startup.
```

Comment: The rails server did not launch, ```bundler: command not found: rails```.Have you run ```bundle install``` before booting rails

Comment: @Spikie Looking at the first line it appears to be running `bundle install` there

Answer (score 0):

Ruby apps must be deployed with all the required [gems](https://rubygems.org/gems). You may refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-ruby) which describes how Azure App Service runs Ruby apps in a Linux container, and how you can customize the behavior of App Service when needed.

You may investigate this [tutorial for Build a Ruby and Postgres app in Azure App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-ruby-postgres-app)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by, "must be deployed with all gems"? Right [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-ruby#customize-deployment) it says the bundle command is ran by default. But it sounds like you are saying I need to install the gems locally and push them to the server.